# проблема с созданием таблички (не таблицы)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вообщем. Я попытался сделать табличку для игры. задача : когда подходишь к объекту "табличка"
и нажимаешь клавишу "E" то появляется табло с текстом и кнопками для листания него.
Проблема : если этих тобличек 2 и больше то появляются все табло с текстами.

я как сделать чтобы табличка не делала этого и появлялся только 1 табло.
если другая табличка другое табло.

```
public class табличка : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tablo;

    public GameObject text_1;
    public GameObject text_2;
    public GameObject text_3;
    public GameObject text_4;
    public GameObject text_5;

    int texting = 1;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && CompareTag("E"))
        {
            tablo.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
        switch (texting)
        {
            case 1:
                text_1.SetActive(true);
                text_2.SetActive(false);
                text_5.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 2:
                text_1.SetActive(false);
                text_2.SetActive(true);
                text_3.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 3:
                text_2.SetActive(false);
                text_3.SetActive(true);
                text_4.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 4:
                text_3.SetActive(false);
                text_4.SetActive(true);
                text_5.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 5:
                text_1.SetActive(false);
                text_4.SetActive(false);
                text_5.SetActive(true);
                break;
            

        }
        if(texting <= 1)
        {
            texting = 1;
        }
        if (texting >= 5)
        {
            texting = 5;
        }
    }
    public void textingUp()
    {
        texting++;
    }
    public void textingDovn()
    {
        texting--;
    }
    public void textingExit()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        texting = 1;
        tablo.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

и плиз
не ругайте если код ужасен.
вы все с чего то начинали .

Comment: где реализация этого "когда подходишь к объекту" - выходит подходить не обязательно, нужно поставить триггер https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: с триггером спасибо . но проблема не решена.
появляются все табло с текстами если табличек с текстом 2 и больше

Comment: @кирилл у тебя скрипт висит на всех "табличка"х. создай отдельный класс и при нажатии вызывай метод <<просмотра>> для конкретной таблички